# Android Studio не импортирует библиотеки

Tags: android-studio, библиотеки

Я пытаюсь использовать Bottom Sheet для своего проекта из этого сайта https://medium.com/android-bits/android-bottom-sheet-30284293f066. На сайте сказано, что необходимо подключить библиотеку в ваш проект:

```
dependencies {
    //replace X.X.X with the latest version
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:X.X.X'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:X.X.X'
}
```

Для подключения я проделываю след. манипуляции:

1. Заходим в`File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies`,нажимаем `+`, с помощью `search` находим необходимые библиотеки. Подтверждаем все и закрываем `Project Structures`.
2. Прописываем в конфиге `build.gradle`

   `dependencies {
       //replace X.X.X with the latest version
       implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
       implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
   }`

Я использую последнюю версии библиотеки, 28.0.0 последняя версия на данный момент.
В новой версии Android Studio вместо `compile` необходимо писать `implementation`.
Далее я нажимаю `sync now`.

После проделывания всех манипуляций, я захожу в `MainActivity` и импортирую следующие библиотеки:

```
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialog;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

свойства`gradle.properties`:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app's APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
```

`build.gradle` моего проекта:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

а также `build.gradle` модуля:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testgradle"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

Все они начинают подчеркиваться красным светом. Я все еще не могу разобраться, что я упустил, какие манипуляции не проделал? Надеюсь вы поможете решить данную проблему.

Comment: И что пишет-то, там где красным подчеркнуто (мышку наведи туда).

Comment: пишет Cannot resolve symbol 'design'

Comment: Покажите ещё и основной `build.gradle` + `gradle.properties` - возможно у вас включены `androidx` библиотеки и из-за этого конфликт. Указанные вами версии - устарели уже и не поддерживаются. Вместо них следует использовать аналоги из `androidx` пакета

Comment: уже поправил вопрос, дал доступную вам информацию о моих свойствах build.gradle